# вместо unicode-символов putwchar выдает невесть что

Tags: c, unicode

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <wchar.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Введите путь к файлу-источнику\n");
        exit(EX_USAGE);
    }

    FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    wchar_t sym;
    do {
        sym = fgetwc(in);
        putwchar(sym);
        if (sym != L'\n')
            putwchar(L' ');
    } while (sym != WEOF);

    putwchar(L'\n');    

    return 0;
}
```

выдает

```
me@gentoo ~ $ ./a.out in
� � � � � � � �   � � � � � � � �   � � � � � � � � 
� � � � � � � �   � � � � � �   � � � � � � ? � 
me@gentoo ~ $
```

Comment: В какой кодировке у вас сохранён `in`, какая локаль и кодировка консоли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В начале программы добавьте две строки:

```
#include <locale.h>
. . .
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Всё у Вас получится! :-)

Comment: решено, спасибо. кстати, почему выдается предупреждение
`fgetwc.c: В функции «main»:
fgetwc.c:23:15: предупреждение: сравнение знакового и беззнакового целых выражений [-Wsign-compare]
  } while (sym != WEOF);`
?

Comment: Из-за того, что sym и WEOF объявлены по разному. Кто-то из них,как знаковый тип, другой - как беззнаковый. Это надо в хидерах смотреть, на память не помню. Но, в данном контексте, на это предупреждение можно не обращать внимания.